# you can type a code to manipulate an Array-List of type char

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program whereby each player  has to enter a word with the available letters in the alphabet list. When a player enters a word the letters of that word get removed from the alphabet list. this is what I tried but it gives this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException.java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast
>   java.lang.CharSequence

```
System.out.println(""+ player.getuser() + " enter your word :");
word = sc.next();
 //an if stament to removethe letters that matches the word entered by the players
if(word.contains((Charsequence) alphList))
   alphList.remove(word);
```

Comment: The exception is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want it the other way around. `String.contains` ask for a `CharSequence` and you have an `ArrayList`

If your `ArrayList` is of `string`, then you need to do: `alphList.contains(word)`